# How to remove values in dictionary if key isn't in range?

Tags: python, dictionary

What I need to do is remove values from a dictionary if the keys are not in an entered range. Here is my current code.

````
while True:
  player = input("Input player:")
  if player == '':
    break
  score = int(input("Input score:"))

  playerDict[player] = score

minimum = int(input("Input a minimum score:"))
maximum = int(input("Input a maximum score:"))```
````

If the keys are not in range of minimum to maximum then I want to remove them. Everything I've tried won't work as I don't know what the entered values will be.

Comment: Where do you have a dict with integer __keys__ ??? And what have you tried that "didn't work" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`dictionary comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in your_dictionary.items() if minimum < k < maximum}
```

Or if you would like something perhaps more clear

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in your_dictionary.items():
    if minimum < k < maximum: 
        new_dict[k] = v
```

Notice that `minimum < k < maximum` (as opposed to `minimum < k and k < maximum`) is allowed in python because of [`operator chaining`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

---

Or, with `filter` and `dict`

```
new_dict = dict(filter(lambda kv: minimum < kv[0] < maximum, your_dictionary.items()))
```

(I think this is the worst one)

Comment: "Or, functionally" dictionary comprehensions are functional programming constructs already. They are inspired by Haskell list comprehensions.

Comment: sure @juanpa.arrivillaga